# Using macros for string concatenation

Tags: objective-c, macros

I want to create macro that receives 2 arguments: `NSString` and `ObjCBool` and returns `NSString`.

I'm not familiar a lot with macros, anyway this is what I did so far:

```
#define fooOne(url)\
          @"1111111" url

 #define fooTwo(url)\
          @"2222222" url


#define root(url, flag)\
   if(!flag)fooOne(url)\
   else fooTwo(url)
```

Here I have 2 problems:

1) when I call `fooOne` as:

```
NSString *url = @"zzz";
NSLog(@"%@", fooOne(url)); 
// expected log should be: "1111111 zzz"
```

I get error: `Expected ')'`

2) When I call `root(url, flag)` as:

```
BOOL flag = YES;
NSString *url = @"zzz";
NSLog(@"%@", root(url, flag)); 
// expected log should be: "2222222 zzz"
```

I get an error: `Expected expression`

please help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile-time string concatenation only works with string literals. At compile time `@"hello, " @"world"` is combined into a new string literal `@"hello, world"`. This doesn't work with strings contained in variables — `@"blabla" url` is not a valid expression, even if `url` contains a string literal at runtime. You would have to call your macros with the literal inside: `fooOne(@"zzz")`, which would expand to `@"blabla" @"zzz"`.

If you want to combine strings at runtime, you'll need to use `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, or append the strings.

Comment: how about `BOOL`? is my `root` method valid? or I have problem with arguments only?

Comment: @snaggs The macro expands to a literal expression. So `root(url, flag)` expands to the literal expression `if (!flag) fooOne(url) else fooTwo(url)` (which then further expands `fooOne` and `fooTwo`). The flag is not being used in any special way at compile time, so this is valid. The issue is with your `foo` macros.

Comment: That being said, you have to keep in mind that the macro expansion is literal. So you cannot write `NSLog(@"%@", root(url, flag)); `, since it expands to `NSLog(@"%@", if (!flag) fooOne(url) else fooTwo(url));`, which is not valid (you cannot have an if-statement inline like that). To make that sort of use valid, you can use a ternary statement instead: `NSLog(@"%@", flag ? fooTwo(url) : fooOne(url));` → `#define root(url, flag) ((flag) ? (fooTwo(url)) : (fooOne(url))`